# BSODs by WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR & CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT in Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I'm constantly getting BSODs due to:

> WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR
>
> CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT

Also, I've gotten these a few times:

> MACHINE_CHECK_EXCEPTION
>
> Reboot and select proper boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected boot device and press a key

I used BlueScreenView and came to know that it was caused by these "**halmacpi.dll**" and a "**hal.dll**"

I've shared a screenshot & the link of .dmp files.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9YwnjWuZdn_b01oZ2J4WFlnZXM/view?usp=sharing

[image]

I've tried updating some few drivers in Device Manager and also tried uninstalling some of the Windows Updates but I still get those BSODs while doing that and it's not showing any positive results.

Sometimes my PC lasts for an hour and so or, mostly it won't even last 10 minutes stable before getting a BSOD.
Earlier it used to be stable when I newly upgraded from Windows 7 Ultimate (32bit) to Windows 10 Pro (32bit) (though it did happened sometimes in Win7).

My PC Specs are:
Intel i5-2500k 3.30 GHz
Corsair RAM 4GB
Asus P8P67 Motherboard
Corsair CX600 PSU
AMD Radeon HD 6850
Edit_1
I'm also getting 'Press F1 to recover BIOS settings' error everyday & because of CPU Over temperature once.
It's showing that my BIOS is up to date, sometimes when I go to BIOS and select the turbo mode to boost performance and or disable the F1 error. It resets itself on its own the next time.
My default apps also get reset to Windows' default.
I ran Windows Memory Diagnosis tool and it showed no error. Also sometimes when in BIOS the CPU fan speed is shown low like in 1000s or it'd be in 2000s, and I've also experienced a lag there (in BIOS) for no reason.

Help me!

Comment: It’s most likely a hardware problem.

Comment: sir i know it's due to a hardware glitch, how should i solve it?

Comment: I was referring to the more permanent kind of problem. To pinpoint the problem, swap all components one by one.

Comment: share the dmp files, otherwise I can't help

Comment: done sir, please tell me the solution ASAP! thanks!

Comment: I checked 2 dumps abd both show **Internal timer** error. run a CPU stress test to see if the CPU is damaged

Comment: Thanks for responding. How should I be solving this Internal timer error? and I ran the CPU stress test using HeavyLoad for about 20 mins, and the graph was stable... BTW I've updated the link with a few more dmp files I've encountered recently.

Comment: this doesn't fix it, but if you get a BSOd during the stress test the chances are high the CPU is damaged

Comment: Alright I know that the CPU isn't damaged but I'm still getting BSODs so what do you suggest I should be doing in order to stop them? And should I upload the link with more dmps, if you need to look at 'em?

Comment: look for BIOS update also test the RAM with memtest86+

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I'm also getting this 'Press F1 to go to BIOS' error everyday. And it's showing me that my BIOS is up to date, but yeah sometimes whenever I go to BIOS and select the turbo mode to boost performance and or disable the F1 error, it resets itself on its own the next time. I ran Windows Memory Diagnosis tool and it showed no error. Also sometimes when in BIOS the CPU fan speed is shown low like in 1000s or it'd be in 2000s, and I've also experienced a lag (in BIOS) there for no reason. Help me!